Origin -destination matrix in QGIS
I'm trying to calculate time taken to nearest hospital, from population centroids with OD Matrix in QGIS. I actually want to calculate walk-time, so I set the default speed to 5km/h. The total cost I'm getting is very high, is their something wrong with my parameters or is OD only for drive-time and drive-speed, so a higher speed value? Also what is the difference between entry cost, exit cost and network cost and total cost?
I want to calculate walk-time so I calculated time-optimization with a speed of 5km/h. I'm getting very high values in minutes like 200, 150.
